# How to highlight multiple words in JavaScript with button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make it so one or more specific words is highlighted with a button click.

The word is hard-coded in JavaScript. I also want this highlighted feature to not be case sensitive.

In the below code, the word "agreement" will highlight, but only one word - not multiple words or multiple case types.

The goal is for one button to highlight one or more words and another button to clear the highlight. I am able to do this but only for one instance of the word.

```js
$('#clickpurpleagreement').click(function() {
  highlightpurpleagreement('agreement')
});

function highlightpurpleagreement(text) {
  console.log($('#inputText').text());
  //inputText = document.getElementById("inputText")
  var innerHTML = $('#inputText').text();
  var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
  if (index >= 0) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlightpurpleagreementword'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
    $('#inputText').html(innerHTML);
  }

}

$('#clear').click(function() {
  clearpurple('agreement')
});

function clearpurple(text) {
  console.log($('#inputText').text());
  //inputText = document.getElementById("inputText")
  var innerHTML = $('#inputText').text();
  var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
  if (index >= 0) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='clearpurple'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
    $('#inputText').html(innerHTML);
  }

}
```

```css
.highlightpurpleagreementword {
  background-color: #847bba;
}

.clearpurple {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="button" id="clear"><strong>Clear Highlight</strong></a>
  <a class="button button-purple" id="clickpurpleagreement"><strong>Agreement</strong></a>
</div>

<div class="credits" id="inputText">The agreement, Agreement, or agreement is in review</div>
```

Comment: [Maybe helpfull](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hk98oq?file=index.js)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `indexOf` use a Regular Expression to find all occurrences of a substring:

```js
function wordIndexes(text) {
    var innerHTML = $('#inputText').text();
    var regexp = new RegExp(text, 'igm');
    while(match = regexp.exec(innerHTML)) {
        console.log(match.index);
    }
}

wordIndexes('agreement');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="credits" id="inputText">The agreement, Agreement, or agreement is in review</div>
```

### Edit

You've asked for the full JavaScript that would allow you to hard-code the word that needs to be highlighted:

```js
$('#clickpurpleagreement').click(function() {
  highlightpurpleagreement('agreement')
});

function highlightpurpleagreement(text) {
  var innerHTML = $('#inputText').text();
  var regexp = new RegExp(text, 'igm');
  var result = '';
  var currentIndex = 0;
  while(match = regexp.exec(innerHTML)) {
    result += innerHTML.substring(currentIndex, match.index) + 
      '<span class="highlightpurpleagreementword">' + innerHTML.substring(match.index, match.index + text.length) + '</span>'
    currentIndex = match.index + text.length;
  }
  result += innerHTML.substring(currentIndex);
  $('#inputText').html(result)
}
```

```css
.highlightpurpleagreementword {
  background-color: #847bba;
}

.clearpurple {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="button" id="clear"><strong>Clear Highlight</strong></a>
  <a class="button button-purple" id="clickpurpleagreement"><strong>Agreement</strong></a>
</div>

<div class="credits" id="inputText">The agreement, Agreement, or agreement is in review</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please help me with the full JavaScript that would allow me to hard-code the word that I want highlighted?

Comment: This is a good effort, but in general I recommend that requests for free labour are turned down. We are drowning them as it is, and it does nothing for the learning journey of new (or lazy) engineers if they can just get free code on demand.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <button id="clear"><strong>Clear Highlight</strong></button>
  <button id="clickpurpleagreement"><strong>Agreement</strong></button>
</div>

<div class="credits" id="inputText">The agreement, Agreement, or agreement is in review</div>
<script>
var colorChanger = document.getElementById("clickpurpleagreement");
colorChanger.addEventListener("click",function() {
  document.getElementById('inputText').style.color = "#847bba";  
});

var colorChanger1 = document.getElementById("clear");
colorChanger1.addEventListener("click",function() {
  document.getElementById('inputText').style.color = "black";  
});
</script>
```

Comment: I only want the word "agreement" highlighted. What is the JavaScript to do this?

Comment: Enclose the word in a font tag and give it a class or id and access that ID